# HighCharts - X axis labels spanning a range pending values

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, data-visualization

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yondaimehokage/nbxka08u/5/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 80,
    plotBorderWidth: 1
},


title: {
    text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
},

xAxis: {
},

yAxis: {
    title: null
},

colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
},

legend: {
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'vertical',
    margin: 0,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    symbolHeight: 280
},

tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
            this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'Sales per employee',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [[0, 0, 10], [1, 0, 19], [2,0, 8], [3, 0, 24], [4, 0, 67], [5, 0, 2], [6, 0, 16], [7, 0, 10], [8, 0, 5], [9, 0, 50]],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#000000'
    }
}]

});
```

Is there a way to have an X axis label span a region of the x axis that is dependent on the values?

In short, I have a heat map graph using HighCharts.  I want to try to achieve something like this (sorry for the Windows Paint rendering):

[image: Mock X axis labeling]

So depending on the values, the X axis color would vary and the centering of the label would be relative to the span of the values that correspond to that data label.

Any thoughts how this could be done?  Tick marks won't do, and this is not a regular interval that I would need to labels to appear either.

Edit: Based on a comment, I guess I need to figure out a way to calculate the pixel width that a range of X value "bars" take up.  So how many pixels do the "bars" that the points that have X values of 1 to 10 take up, how many pixels do the "bars" that the points that have X values of 11 to 25 take up, and so on.

Comment: You haven't defined how you will identify each range, or how you will classify them. But assuming you have that part figured out, I would look at using the `renderer()` function to draw these yourself: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer

Comment: @jlbriggs The X values will determine the label.  So for example, an X values of 1 to 10 would equate to data 1, values 11-25 would equate to Data 2 and so on.  They are always clustered.

Comment: Can you provide a usable sample of data? Or, more preferably, a working fiddle that plots your data like in your illustration?

Comment: @jlbriggs Added a mock example in JS fiddle.